# Why can't I inherit this variable?

Tags: c#, class, protected, derived-class

I get one error with this code:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
```

I'm trying to inherit the itemNo variable from the derived class to put it in to a constructor, but for some reason it's not accepting it.

Full Code:

```
public class InvItem
{
    protected int itemNo;
    protected string description;
    protected decimal price;

    public InvItem()
    {
    }

    public InvItem(int itemNo, string description, decimal price)
    {
        this.itemNo = itemNo;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int ItemNo
    {
        get
        {
            return itemNo;
        }
        set
        {
            itemNo = value;
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return description;
        }
        set
        {
            description = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
        set
        {
            price = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual string GetDisplayText(string sep)
    {
        return itemNo + sep + description + " (" + price.ToString("c") + ")";
    }
}

public class Plant : InvItem
{
    private decimal size;

    public Plant()
    {
    }

    public Plant(int itemNumber, string description, decimal price, decimal size) : base(itemNo, description, price)
    {
        this.Size = size;
    }

    public decimal Size
    {
        get
        {
            return size;
        }
        set
        {
            size = value;
        }
    }

    public override string GetDisplayText(string sep)
    {
        return base.GetDisplayText(sep) + " (" + size + ")";
    }
}
```

It happens in the Plant class constructor with parameters. I've tried setting it to public, private, and protected, but they all yield the same result.

Comment: Variable `itemNo` does not exist, correct variant is `public Plant(int itemNumber, string description, decimal price, decimal size) : base(itemNumber, description, price)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are calling `base` on the constructor, those variables don't even exist yet (the base class hasn't been constructed).

Thus, you can't pass the class member to it in the `base` constructor call. Instead, you needed:

```
public Plant(int itemNumber, string description, decimal price, decimal size) : 
    base(itemNumber, description, price)
{
}
```

This will pass the parameters provided to `Plant` along to the base class, which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Plant(int itemNumber, string description, decimal price, decimal size)
            : base(itemNo, description, price)
        {
            this.Size = size;
        }
```

While you are using it in constructor, you yet do not have access to base class members, so you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the inherited property in your constructor.  Do this:

```
public Plant(int itemNumber, string description, decimal price, decimal size)
    : base(itemNumber, description, price)
{
    this.Size = size;
}
```